# .NET client-server communication over unreliable network

Tags: wcf, web-services, msmq

I am working on new a RIA that will most likely be developed using WPF. This application will communicate with a Web Service over an unreliable network (e.g. 3G).

How do I achieve reliable communication in scenarios like -

1. A "Create" operation was successful
   on the server/WebService (say a new
   record was created) but the response
   containing the record identifier
   couldn't make back it to the client
   application.
2. Process payment which should be an
       atomic operation

Is MSMQ with WCF the best option here or are there known strategies and patterns to achieve reliability on unreliable networks (e.g 3G) without using Messaging Frameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use MSMQ across the HTTP but you'll be much better off if you use the open source [RabbitMQ queuing framework](http://www.rabbitmq.com/how.html). It also includes a WCF binding that you should be able to use for your scenario. WCF with MSMQ is great for inside the firewall but it wasn't designed for the internet in mind.

Comment: What specifically makes RabbitMQ a better choice than MSMQ in this scenario?

Comment: The short answer is that RabbitMQ was designed to use HTTP as one of its native transports and MSMQ was designed to use a proprietary binary transport. MSMQ was later tweaked by Microsoft to work over HTTP but this feature is not supported by an out-of-the-box WCF binding (netMsmqBinding does not work over HTTP). RabbitMQ provides a WCF binding that lets you do messaging over HTTP. RabbitMQ is even supported by Amazon EC2 cloud services so you know it works over the internet. I guess that wasn't too short of an answer... :)

Comment: Update to my comment RabbitMQ's native transport is TCP and there is an experimental HTTP based transport being worked. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Would non messaging framework be an option to explore?

Comment: A non-messaging framework would basically be a regular WCF service with a wsHttpBinding and [Reliable Messaging enabled.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480191.aspx) This mode is "reliable" but it **does not** provide guaranteed message delivery even if the service is down. With RabbitMQ & MSMQ, the message transmission and handling is done at the transport level.

Comment: @JohnBreakwell I didn't realize you were the great [MSMQ plumbers mate!!](http://blog.plumbersmate.eu/) I've scoured your blog over the years for fixes to my various MSMQ woes. I truly appreciate your continued contribution to the unofficial and real world MSMQ documentation. It really saved my butt years ago when I was working on a WCF service that needed to integrate with a legacy MSMQ trigger based application. Thanks!!

Comment: @Sixto thank you. I have used ExpressQ in the past but haven't worked with MSMQ. People around me haven't got a favorable view of MSMQ!